# Browser showing "Cannot GET /api/posts/ " instead of "hello" from res.send('hello')

Tags: node.js, express

My index.js file:

```
//Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const posts = require('./routes/api/posts.js');

//Configuration
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//App object
const app = express();

//Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

//Main app
app.use('api/posts',posts);

//Starting server
app.listen(port,()=>{
  console.log(`server running at ${port}`);
});
```

My Api file:

```
//Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

//Mini app
const router = express.Router();

//Get post
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send('hello');
});

//Add post

//Delete post

module.exports = router;
```

I'm expecting to get "hello" in my browser but constantly getting "Cannot GET /api/posts/" in firefox and postman. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction :-

```js
//Main app
app.use('/api/posts',posts);
```

Comment: @MasudurRahman Glad to be able to help you.